# shell_exec unable to execute command after Imagick constructor

Tags: php, imagick, shell-exec

I have extremely weird issue, which i can't explain for now. I use Imagick library to edit uploaded images and have following peace of code:

```
echo shell_exec( 'which jpegoptim' );
$image = new Imagick( '/path/to/the/image.jpg' );
echo shell_exec( 'which jpegoptim' );
```

The problem is that I receive following output:

```
/usr/bin/jpegoptim

Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'which jpegoptim' in ... line 129
```

This means that `shell_exec` works properly before I create an image object and doesn't work after it. What am I doing wrong?

The image which I use could be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61868050/veteran_car_201643.jpg).

**Update #1:** everything work just fine if I use GD instead of Imagick, but I want to resolve that weird issue with Imagick.

**Update #2:** further more such weird behaviour appears only for certain images, some jpeg images are processed fine, some aren't.

**Update #3:** There is no issues with file permissions, GD processes the same file just fine and shell_exec works fine after it.

**Update #4:** The var dump of the `$image` variable:

```
class Imagick#395 (0) {
}
```

**The question is about shell_exec, which doesn't work after Imagick constructor with certain image passed into it.**

Comment: maybe that you have to chmod your image on linux or attrib +R on Windows, before your 2nd shell_exec

Comment: there is no issue with permissions, GD processes the same image without any problem.

Comment: Can you give the output of `var_dump($image)` for problematic and non-problematic image?

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob added var_dump result which is the same for all images

Comment: @EugeneManuilov can you give the output of `pwd` and `whoami` before and after the `Imagic` instance creation?

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob it shows proper values right before constructor and "unable to execute" after constructor.

Comment: That is very odd. I can't think how this is even possible. One way you might find out is by running strace to see what system calls are being made The script at https://gist.github.com/Danack/de16db746dd2c6a29c8d will run strace and attach it to all PHP-FPM processes. btw this may not be a good question for StackOverflow - maybe open an issue at https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues ?

Comment: Thanks @Danack, will post a bug report there.